# mysql from a result, how to select rows that have same values in 2 column

Tags: mysql

In my MySQL database,  the below query

```
SELECT c.cas_number, c.description c_desc, 
        sm.description sm_desc, sm.id sm_id, sm.component_id,
        c.id 
FROM starting_material sm 
    join component c ON c.id=sm.component_id;
```

returns a portion of data as below

[image]

And from this result, I am trying to select all rows which have the same value for the two columns c_decs and sm_desc

I tried this query but it returns only 2 rows, but I can physically see there are many rows matching

```
select r.cas_number, r.c_desc, r.sm_desc 
from (
        SELECT c.cas_number, c.description c_desc, 
                sm.description sm_desc, sm.id sm_id, sm.component_id,
                c.id 
        FROM starting_material sm 
            join component c ON c.id=sm.component_id
     ) as r
where r.c_desc like r.sm_desc;
```

I also tried this but still only 2 records in the result.

```
SELECT c.cas_number, c.description, sm.description 
FROM starting_material sm 
    join component c ON c.id=sm.component_id
where trim(c.description) = trim(sm.description);
```

**Update:-**

Only matching results are

[image]

Comment: Have tried WHERE col1 = col2 instead of the LIKE?

Comment: Don't use `like` if you want an exact match. It's probably inefficient (as one side needs checked for wildcards and such) and possibly wrong (if it contains those).

Comment: @CoderLee yes even tried that WHERE col1 = col2, did not work too

Comment: @Jay Have you checked that the text format is the same? It should match unless you have something wonky like carriage returns in one but not the other.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
SELECT c.cas_number, c.description, sm.description
FROM starting_material sm 
join component c ON c.id = sm.component_id
where c.description = sm.description
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, guys I did the below steps to find out the issue

By using string compare (STRCMP) I found out which records are not matching. Mostly all records did not match (with value 1) other than 2 records (value 0)

```
SELECT c.cas_number, c.description, sm.description, STRCMP(c.description, sm.description) FROM starting_material sm join component c ON c.id=sm.component_id;
```

[image]

It turns out one of the columns sm.description have a carriage return at the end \r

The below query helped to get all matching records.

```
SELECT c.cas_number, c.description, sm.description FROM starting_material sm join component c ON c.id=sm.component_id
where sm.description like concat(c.description, '\r');
```

I fixed the carriage return with below query

```
update starting_material set description=REPLACE(description,'\r','');
```